# Tkinter project

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to have an input asking file path and when the user fills file path with file name, program must save a file with this file name.Under input I need a text and multiple inputs just for one answer. How can I do that?

Comment: Then what's your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filedialog` of `tkinter`,

Whole code demo:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Text, filedialog

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.text = Text(master)
        self.text.pack()

        self.save_button = Button(master, text="Save as...", command=self.open)
        self.save_button.pack()


    def open(self):
        self._filetypes = [
        ('Text', '*.txt'),
            ('All files', '*'),
            ]
        self.filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.txt',
                                                             filetypes = self._filetypes)
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        f.write(self.text.get('1.0', 'end'))
        f.close()

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So just need to do save file functions, and that's it, and use `open` for saving (writing it)

Comment: I get this error:Desktop\files1".asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv',
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'asksaveasfilename'

Comment: @ertugrulyavuzalp That's funny... Why is `filedialog` a string, also, can you please check if there is any other `filedialog`s in your code?, if there is, rename the variable.